# Rails 3 Authlogic acts_as_authentic undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm getting an error that acts_as_authentic is undefined for rails 3, ruby 1.9.2

My Gemfile has: gem 'authlogic'

The command "bundle show authlogic" shows the correct path where authlogic is installed

My acts_as_authentic appears in a controller:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.login_field = :phone
  end
end
```

Let me know if there's anything else that will be helpful, I'm new to rails so I'm not entirely sure what to post.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I always ask questions on StackOverflow just before I figure it out.  I needed to restart rails server to get it to work.